# Require that a user selects anything but the initial value from a @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a nullable field in a viewmodel that I'm using a DropDownListFor to allow for selection and would like to add validation that only allows the user to submit the form if they  select a different option from the drop down than what they already have stored. It's valid for the user to have a null value stored as their service provider so its not a required field, I just don't want anyone to be able to submit the value they already have. Is a custom validation attribute the way to go here?

```
public class ServiceProviderViewModel
{
    public Guid? SelectedServiceProvider { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ServiceProviderList { get; set; }
}
```

Razor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedServiceProvider, Model.ServiceProviderList, "None", new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Comment: You could try a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `NotEqualTo` attribute, and add a hidden field that contains the current value

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I was already using foolproof in the project so your suggestion worked perfectly.